# flying-saucer is overriding and overlapping the pdf

Tags: java, maven, pdf, pom.xml, flying-saucer

I have read all the supported issues but not having right solution. I have updated flying-saucer dependency from 1 to 9 and finding the issue.

```
<version.oldc.flyingsaucer>1.0</version.oldc.flyingsaucer>
<version.oldc.flyingsaucer.itext>2.0.8</version.oldc.flyingsaucer.itext>
```

to this

```
<version.oldc.flying-saucer-core>9.0.9</version.oldc.flying-saucer-core>
<version.oldc.flying-saucer-pdf>9.0.9</version.oldc.flying-saucer-pdf>
```

and I have added this method in the interface because its not letting me to build successfully.

```
 @Override
    public void preWrite(ITextRenderer iTextRenderer, int pageCount) {  
    }
```

this is causing my pdf overllaped totally when I degrade the version its working fine but I cannot degrade it because there are other issues causing. i have tried all the css tricks which is not helpful. Am I missing anything else. 
I am thinking its because of the method in the interface but its not happening in all pages its happening only for one page in entire document.

[image]

Comment: It seems unlikely that you can just update from version 1 to version 9 and have that work... it also seems unlikely that you're need an empty `preWrite`, so: what does the documentation for v9 say your config and code needs to be structured as?

Comment: yes because xhtmlrenderer has default interface with this abstract method so I am implementing it with empty body